# How can I connect my Cloudflare Pages with my Woocommerce website?

Tags: woocommerce, cloudflare, cloudflare-pages, cloudflare-apps

I have this problem, more specifically I have a site set up on Woocommerce. Recently, I managed to generate a file with all the pages and deployed them on Cloudflare Pages.

Is there any way to make dynamic elements such as the login/registration form or the shopping cart or the add to cart button work the same as if someone was on my sandbox page?

Maybe it's possible to connect all of this in some way through an API?

Create a few Cloudflare Workers, but this workers is not working.